# Is Hashem polite?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, theology, social-convention

This question might be a bit weird, but here's what inspired it.

In an internet forum I frequent, someone posted a wall of text (that is, a long post without any line breaks or paragraphs). I pointed out that posting a wall of text is impolite. He replied, "well, if walls of text are impolite, then the whole Torah is impolite."

This lead me to think - So G-d and the Torah are impolite, what of it? We can think of many instances where G-d's actions or words can be considered impolite. When you rule the entire universe you have the luxury of not being polite.

On the other hand we were made in His image, so if we consider politeness to be a virtue, we should expect G-d to exhibit it as well.

So now I'm curious - should G-d be polite, is he, and do these questions even make sense?

**Addendum**, particularly with response to @DanF:

I should clarify that the point of the other person in the forum wasn't to show that the Torah is impolite. Quite the opposite - he was trying to say that the Torah is obviously polite, and the Torah is a wall of text (DanF points out this isn't actually the case), so walls of text cannot be impolite.

It was I who used this opportunity to idly wonder whether G-d and the Torah should actually be expected to be polite.

The story about that forum clearly was not directly relevant to the question, but it was my attempt (unsuccessful, apparently) to establish the background for the question and clarify what it is that I mean.

Ultimately it was an open-ended question about an issue I found interesting, which I hoped could expand a bit my understanding about such matters. I recognize that SE isn't the best fit for such questions, but I couldn't think of a better place to ask.

Comment: What do you mean by polite?

Comment: @sabbahillel: I'm not using the word with any specialized meaning. To the extent that the standard meaning is ambiguous, answerers can feel free to choose a meaning to go on. Clearly the question is quite open-ended.

Comment: I'm not overly technical. What is a "text wall"? I think that if you edit in a brief description, it would help us see the analogy to the idea that the Torah is a huge "text wall". (I don't even understand what that means, now.) G-d is "gracious" meaning that he does kindness for humans even if they may not deserve it. Would you consider graciousness as part of "politeness"?

Comment: @mbloch: Actually, I don't understand the term to mean a picture at all. Rather it's a long text without any line breaks or separation to paragraphs. This is not done for any particular response, but rather due to laziness or poor writing style. This is harder to read than properly formatted text, and thus posting in such a way can be considered impolite. The Torah can definitely be considered a wall of text - my understanding is that as originally given (and largely as it is copied now), it is a monolithic stream of text.

Comment: Seems to vague and hence broad / unclear.

Comment: @DanF: I thought it should be clear enough, but seeing as you were unaware of the meaning and mbloch had a different interpretation, I edited to explain briefly. I don't think kind in the sense of "charitable" is what I think of as "polite". Politeness is less about what you do and more about how you do it. For example "Here, take this $1000 donation. Now get out of my sight you scoundrel!" is charitable but very impolite/rude.

Comment: The responder on your forum is incorrect. If you view a written Torah, it has numerous paragraph breaks. It looks nothing like a text wall. I sense that the forum person has other reasons to think that the Torah is impolite, but, honestly, this person doesn't sound well-informed to make that statement. At any rate, if the only reason is that the Torah is a text wall, then certainly, the Torah is NOT impolite, because he's just plainly wrong. You're welcome to copy / paste this entire comment as a response.

Comment: Meni, welcome to Mi Yodeya. I should have done that first! This is one of many examples of a question that got closed as "unclear" after you have two good answers. I agree that the question is quite vague as the term "politeness" is extremely vague, itself. It is both cultural and personal, as you can tell. It would be a clearer question, I think, if you asked if the Torah attempts to teach people to act politely. Additionally, your forum story seems irrelevant and, I think throws things off, here. I've already commented on that. You should narrow down the focus of your question, perhaps.

Comment: @DanF: I guess it's been a while since I've viewed a written Torah :). Anyway, I've edited the question to add a response to the issues you've raised; the question itself is probably not salvageable.

Comment: I wonder if, to avoid confusion, the entire bit about the forum should be removed, leaving “can Hashem be considered polite?”

Comment: Agree with ^^^. You're addendum is tangential information. It is a nice story, but, I think it clutters and confuses the question. The question is always "salvageable", BTW, as you can (and should) edit it as much as possible.

Comment: @DanF: The question was considered unclear, and I don't see a way to clarify it other than 1. Explain what inspired it (which backfired) or 2. Change it to a different question than the one I wanted to ask. Which means it is not salvageable. I accept the decision to close it. The addendum was more of a post mortem, I just wanted to explain myself, and to respond to your concerns (which would be too long for a comment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One cannot define God as being either polite or un-polite, both attributes would limit Him and he is by definition unlimited. We only know and understand God through His Torah and the laws (*halachot*) He wants us to observe.

First of all, **God chose to write His Torah in a refined and polished way** to teach us. The Gemara (in [Pesachim 3a](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.3a.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) brings a number of examples of refined language where God chooses to write extra letters or different words to avoid unpolite or unrefined language, e.g.,

- [Bereishit 7:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.7.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en): "Of the clean animals, of the animals that are not clean, of the birds, and of everything that creeps on the ground" -- the Torah uses "that are not clean" instead of writing "unclean"
- [Devarim 23:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.23.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en): "If anyone among you has been rendered unclean by a nocturnal emission, he must leave the camp, and he must not reenter the camp." -- the Torah uses "has been rendered unclean" instead of writing "impure"

(see more examples in the [continuation of the gemara](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.3a.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).)

**Second there are many other *halachot* linked to politeness, e.g.,**

- clean speech (*[Nivul Peh](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=5213)*)
- praising a bride in front of the groom even if one has to exagerate a bit ([Ketubot 17a](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.17a.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
- or the many halachot and Torah examples of *derech Eretz* (e.g., see [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3469552/jewish/What-Is-Derech-Eretz.htm) and [there](https://www.ou.org/torah/parsha/parsha-from-ou/derech-eretz-kadma-ltorah-mensch/)).

Answer (score 3):

G-d is polite. Even at the risk of encouraging polytheists G-d said "Let us create man" (Bereishit 1:26) consulting with the angels, instead of "I shall create man" ([Bereishit Rabba 8:7](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14385&st=&pgnum=21)). Even though in the context it made no sense (angels have no free will, G-d is the Creator of everything), He did this to be a good example and teach us proper manners.

Comment: You could make this answer much more valuable by [edit]ing in a clear reference  to the episode you're describing.

Comment: Was it to teach us politeness and manners? Or to teach us humility, which is related but distinct?

Comment: How do you know this is why he said that? Is he always polite or just sometimes? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: @NaftaliTzvi You may have the Creation Narrative and the commentaries on it memorized, but not all readers, especially of this quite accessible question, have. If you refer+ link to the relevant verses and to the commentaries that are the bases for your conclusions, you will make this a more compelling answer to the question at hand as well as a more valuable read for anyone who comes across it.

Comment: What??? Consulting with others prior to making a major decision is proof of politeness? I'm not seeing that deduction. We call G-d a parent (father, usually.) If a parent asked their child each time they wanted to go somewhere, "Would you like to go?" because they thought it was the polite thing to do, chances are, 80% of the time, they wouldn't go.